# Request DTO and Response DTO json for request body and response body respectively

Tags: json, request, response, dto, spring-restcontroller

In REST-WebServices, I use DTO classes for Request and Response. My Request Dto and Response Dto are essentially the same - structure wise but during request I provide values to only certain fields (caseId and userId here) but in response barring editedBy and modifiedDate, I get values for all other fields of the Dto.

```
public class ProcedureRequestDTO{
 private ProcedureDTO procedure;
      // getters & setters
}

public class ProcedureResponseDTO{
 private ProcedureDTO procedure;
    // getters & setters
}

public class ProcedureDTO{
 private Integer procedureId;
 private Integer procedureName;
 private Integer caseId;
 private Integer userId;
 private Integer ownerId;
 private Integer editedBy;

 @JsonInclude(value=Include.ALWAYS)
 @JsonDeserialize(using=ZonedDateTimeJsonDeserializer.class)
 @JsonSerialize(using=ZonedDateTimeJsonSerializer.class)
 @JsonFormat(shape=Shape.NUMBER)
 private ZonedDateTime createdDate;

 @JsonInclude(value=Include.ALWAYS)
 @JsonDeserialize(using=ZonedDateTimeJsonDeserializer.class)
 @JsonSerialize(using=ZonedDateTimeJsonSerializer.class)
 @JsonFormat(shape=Shape.NUMBER)
 private ZonedDateTime modifiedDate;
    // getters & setters
}
```

So should I include all fields in my request json or only those fields which have a value. Here are my request and response jsons:

request json:-

```
{
  "procedure":{
       "caseId": 1,
       "userId": 1
   }
}
```

response json:-

```
{
  "procedure":{
      "procedureId": 1,
      "procedureName": "proc1",
      "caseId": 1,
      "userId": 1,
      "ownerId": 1,
      "editedBy": null,
      "createdDate": 1461059413000,
      "modifiedDate": null
   }
}
```

Should my request and response jsons be like this itself or should I send the entire dto in my request json? If there are any other mistakes with my Dto class please do mention them also.

Answer (score 0):

Your request json will be like this only.
In request DTO json, you can see only those fields which carry some value.
Like in you case *caseId* and *userId*.

and about response json, it is also fine but *caseId* and *userId* can be redundent from the response json. As you already know their values.